# Saving Data Into MongoDB (with using mongoose) When HTML Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a basic blog app and I want to save users' data when they click submit button. I'm using mongoose for saving data in MongoDB. I wrote some code but it doesn't worked. I'm new to this website things and I'm trying to learn.

There is code that I wrote for save into DB:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/user");

const db_URI = 'my db_uri in here, idk about security so i didn't write it'; 
const button = document.getElementById("submit-btn");

mongoose.connect(db_URI)

button.onclick = function() {
    var user = new User( { # I made this variable for just test
        name:"qwe",
        password: "123",
        email: "example@hotmail.com"
    }); 

    user.save()
};
```

This code is for my front-end part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SIGN UP HERE</title>

    </head>


    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <div>
                <label id="name-lbl">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Your nickname here">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>E-mail: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email here">
            </div>
            <div>  
                <label>Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Your password here">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Confirm password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Confirm your password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
            
        </form>
        
        <script src="../database/db_processes.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Frontend and backend js are both different; You need to implement a server like express to get that done.

Comment: Okay. But how can I save users' input to a database without using any framework?

Comment: You cant; or use firebase; which has some capabilities to this,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up some things here. Your backend application (your first code snippet) should be running "server side" using Node. How are you running it now? Also the first code snippet would not have access to the frontend components, like buttons and divs.

What I would suggest is to go through this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs to learn the basics of the architecture(Client-server architecture).  In part 3 they go through how to connect with Mongoose.

Comment: So should I use a framework like Express to run first code and connect it with front-end side?

Comment: @statist31 Yes, the tutorial highlights this. Your browser will send a network request to your backend(Node application). Express is framework that helps you handle requests.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use REST URI endpoints to do your data saving, updating, viewing, finding records, etc. I have done a complete tutorial on this using mongoose, node and express so feel free to check it out at : https://ezani.medium.com/creating-a-crud-node-js-rest-service-with-express-js-and-mongodb-mongoose-72ad173b542b